# User: arn:aws:sts::<ACCOUNT_ID>:assumed-role/<REGION_ID>/amplifyadmin is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I currently have a function called *notifFunc* within an AWS Amplify project that is attempting to invoke SNS:Publish (from the AWS.SNS() class).  I am attempting to test the function by running *amplify mock function notifFunc*, but am receiving the following error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
  },
  "body": "{\"message\":\"User: arn:aws:sts::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:assumed-role/<SERVER_REGION>/amplifyadmin is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: <PHONE_NUMBER> because no identity-based policy allows the SNS:Publish action\",\"code\":\"AuthorizationError\",\"time\":\"2023-08-28T15:41:49.680Z\",\"requestId\":\"cd03bfc8-2668-5c9b-a8a9-e2aee41584c3\",\"statusCode\":403,\"retryable\":false,\"retryDelay\":0.4495027262455986}"
}
```

For clarification, I am attempting to use SNS:Publish to publish a text message directly to a specified phone number (rather than to an AWS Topic).  I'm assuming that this error is relating to a lack of permissions specified somewhere in the AWS console, but I do not know where I would set such permissions.  Where would this be done? Or, if it is a different issue, how do I fix this?

Below is my code where I am invoking SNS:Publish:

```
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
 const sns = new AWS.SNS()
 
 exports.handler = async (event) => {
     const contact = event.body.contact
 
     let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(`Message sent to ${contact}.`)
    };
     try {
         let params = {
             Message: 'This is a test message.',
             PhoneNumber: contact,
         }
        const resp = await sns.publish(params).promise()
        console.log(resp)
     } catch (error) {
         return {
             statusCode: 400,
             headers: {
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
             },
             body: JSON.stringify(error)
         }
     }
     return response
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant the `amplifyadmin` role permission for `SNS:Publish` action as the error message states.

You can do this in the IAM console under Roles. Either attach a managed policy directly, such as `AmazonSNSFullAccess`, or create an inline policy (recommended - principle of least privilege).